# Unable to test web service deployed on server

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, glassfish-3, jelastic

I have developed and published a Java web service on Glassfish server using Netbeans. I can test and use the wsdl file properly using my local application. When I deployed the war file on the server (temporarily I am using jelastic.com as my server), I can access the wsdl file using the URL

http://fesdvi.jelastic.servint.net/FESWebService/Diagnose?WSDL

But cannot test the web service using url

http://fesdvi.jelastic.servint.net/FESWebService/Diagnose?Tester

It gives me following error message

---

Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL (removed http:// as cannot post more than 2 links) fesdvi.jelastic.servint.net/FESWebService/Diagnose?WSDL

### Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security

PS: I am not using secured http.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Following is the extract from the server-instance.log

[ERROR] Connection refused

Failed to read the WSDL document: because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.|#]

Failed to parse the WSDL.|#]

### wsimport failed|#]

Moreover I am trying to find the wsdl on the server but I am not able to find, I am still exploring the application deployment structure in jelastic..

Comment: Were there more details, like exceptions or similar, in the server logs?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root cause of the issue is wrong endpoints settings,
since you have uploaded your project with local machine settings.
It is possible to see list of all Web Service endpoints at the Admin Console. After you have logged to it, look at tree in the left, find item "Applications" expand it and click on your WebApplication. You will see the table, in action column you will find "View Endpoint" links (They should contain the URL of your environment and correct ports).

Also, I think that the Eclipse plugin from Jelastic (http://docs.jelastic.com/eclipse-plugin-user-manual) will help you to solve this issues. 
P.S. If this will not help, you should to contact with your Hosting Provider Support and ask them about the help.

Comment: Thank you leo. I have installed jelastic plugin in eclipse and will try out deploying from it. Thanks again!!